# Fatal: Unable to access git: operation timed out while pushing code

Tags: git, github

I have this issue about pushing my code to GitHub. every time I try to push a code to any repository I get this error:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/HuangLinBao/Facebook-page.git/': Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received`

to the point that I have to manually upload the code files to the repository.

tried pushing with VS Code, IntelliJ, Php Storm, and nothing happened. I even tried publishing other repositories and kept getting the mentioned error with an empty repo of course

Comment: What have you done to get the error?

Comment: Network problem. Cannot be fixed at SO, should be fixed locally. Ask you network admins.

Comment: @ user202729  ```git push origin master``` after committing the code and everything

Comment: @phd I am connected to wifi via mobile hotspot so what can I do?

Comment: Can you open https://github.com in a browser? Just to check the site is not blocked completely. Ask you mobile provider what's the problem. Try using VPN to work around censorship.

Comment: @phd yes I can open github.com with no problems..I can upload the code manually but I don't know why pushing and cloning doesn't work

Comment: Either you configured proxy in a browser; then copy proxy configuration to git. Or you don't have a proxy but configured proxy in git; then remove proxy config from git.

Comment: @phd how can I do all this...I don't know that much about networks